# How can i get groups to which user is group manager in og and profile2?

Tags: 7, organic-groups, users

I am using profile 2 and Organic Groups module on my site . I just need to know what should I put in query to get the group ids to which user is manager. Using this query i am getting the group ids of groups to which user is member.

```
  $result = $query
    ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'og_membership')
    ->propertyCondition('entity_type', 'user')
    ->propertyCondition('etid', $account->uid)
    ->propertyCondition('state', OG_STATE_ACTIVE)
    ->execute();
```

what should i put instead of `og_membership` to get the ids of groups user is manager to.